# AWS Java SDK: AssumeRole from EC2 instance profile?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk-java-2.0

I have an application running on an EC2 instance that has an IAM profile that has EC2 describe on the account in which it resides. It also has AssumeRole for another account (that role grants EC2 describe as well). Here is what my IAM role on the principal account looks like:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:Describe*",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "{SID}",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRole"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::{ACCT_NUM}:role/{ROLE_NAME}"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is the IAM role from the secondary account:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:Describe*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
     ]
}
```

Basically what I need to do is get the EC2 instances from both accounts. Is this possible with the current SDK? Currently I am only getting the instances from the principal account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can with the SDK. After you list the EC2 instances using credentials from the main (default) account, you then use STS to call AssumeRole() to get credentials for the cross account. Then list those EC2 instances.

Comment: For the call to AssumeRole() do I need to provide the ARN/Session name? Is there anyway to get them from the instance profile on which the application is running?

Comment: You can only assign one role to an instance. To assume another role, you have to specify its full ARN. What language will be using?

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-api.html

Comment: Thanks for the info. Looks like what I'm wanting to do isn't really possible without specifying the ARN. I was hoping to get that info from the instance metadata but the problem there is that you don't have to enumerate roles. So even if I got it from the instance itself, I still wouldn't know which role(s) the instance has access to.

Answer (score 3):

Adding `ec2:AssumeRole` does not automatically propagate commands across the accounts.

You must call `ec2:DescribeInstances` once for each AWS account & region that you want to pull instance information from.

Your IAM role for EC2 gives you access to the primary account. Calling `ec2:DescribeInstances` with those credentials alone will give you EC2 instance information for that account alone.

Next, you need to call `ec2:AssumeRole` to receive new credentials for the secondary account. Once you have those, you use those to call `ec2:DescribeInstances` for the secondary account.